# Maximum and Minimum values from a summed Formula in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: global-variables, max, formula, crystal-reports-2008, minimum

Maximum and Minimum values from a summed Formula problem

Hello, I am currently using Crystal Reports 2008 which is getting its data from an Oracle database.  I have looked into this at length and I have been unable to find the information I need.  I have query about getting the Maximum and Minimum values from a given formula which totals 2 or more fields.  A snapshot of the information I am using is:

```
Field1 = dB1.Left_Serious
Field2 = dB1.Left_Dangerous
Field3 = @Tester
Formula = @LeftTot
```

Fields 1+2 are the total score given by the Tester for each Left Test.

```
Test   Field1   Field2   Field3
1      2.0      4.0      J Adams
2      1.0      1.0      J Adams
3      1.0      0.0      S Grey
4      0.0      1.0      S Grey
5      5.0      0.0      D Jones
6      5.0      8.0      D Jones
```

The formula to get the Grand Total for each Tester’s Left Test uses a grouping by Tester:

```
@LeftTot  
Sum ({dB1.Left_Serious}, {@Tester}) + Sum (dB1.Left_Dangerous}, {@Tester})
```

Using the above details we get:

```
J Adams = 8.0 
S Grey = 2.0 
D Jones = 18.0
```

The Maximum figure is therefore 18.0 and the minimum figure is 2.0 and the required difference is 16.0.

The problem I have is I cannot use the Maximum or Minimum commands as Crystal 2008 will not let you use the Summary Functions like Maximum on a formula that sums two fields.  I know you could create a new aggregate field in the database which would solve the problem however I currently do not have administrator access to the databases and cannot create any new data tables or fields.

I have tried to get the ball rolling by using the following code in 3 new formulas:

```
@LeftTotGrpHdr
//This Formula needs to be placed into the Group Header to reset variable
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar LEFTTL:=0

@LeftTotGrpFtr
//This Formula needs to be placed into the Group Footer to display variable
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar LEFTTL

@LeftTotCr
//This Formula declares and works out Total Left Tests 
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar LEFTTL:=LEFTTL + {@LeftTot}
```

However when I try to use

```
Maximum({@LeftTotCr})
```

in a new formula I still get the error message “This field cannot be summarised.”

Is there another way to do this?

Cheers

Daveyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this.

When you summarize the value at the same time store the values in array and retrive maximum and minimum from the array.

```
    //@LeftTot  
    Shared StringVar Array x;

    x:=x+totext(Sum ({dB1.Left_Serious}, {@Tester}) + Sum (dB1.Left_Dangerous}, {@Tester}));
1
```

Now create one more formula `@display`

```
EvaluateAfter(@LeftTotal);
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared StringVar Array x;

Maximum(x);
```

In the same way do for minimum using the `minimum` function.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hello Siva

Thanks for getting back to me.  I think I follow what you’re doing here however when I try to set up this formula:

    Shared StringVar Array x;

    x:=x+totext(Sum ({dB1.Left_Serious}, {@Tester}) +Sum            (dB1.Left_Dangerous}, {@Tester}));

I get the error message:

    This array must be subscripted. For Example: Array [i].

Any ideas?

Comment: Right now I don't have tool with me... changed the code.. let me know how it works.. problem is with the `array` so removed the array and storing the value in string and finding the maximum of the string

Comment: @Dave-69 Changed the code and tested as well... its working for me.. now you can use the above code

Comment: Hello Again Siva, I have tried again but can't get either to work. The first informs me that maximum(x) only works on formula’s and the second just sets the formula to 1.  Am I inserting formula into the wrong location?  Can you advise where I should be placing your array formula’s?

Comment: @Dave-69 I gave the formula after implementation and it worked perfectly for me.. `//@LeftTot  ` in detail part where you get all rows and supress the formula don't print it.. `@display` place in footer.. to get the maximum value.. you took wrong `@Lefttot` is first one and `@display` is second one.

Comment: Hello Siva....sorry for being dense but that works perfectly now...you mate are a star!!

Comment: Hi Siva, sorry for getting back to you but I have hit a snag with using the arrays and thought you may already know what I need to do. Whenever the sum of the two fields equals zero for all the testers and I try to get the maximum(x) I get the error message "The size of the array must be greater than 0".  Is there a way to default any of this type of array to zero?

Comment: Hi @Dave-69 no problem.... `sum of the two fields equals zero ` means you have two arrays and sum of both is `0`. right?.. I have one question here.. if array doesn't have any data then what is the purpose of taking the `Maximum(x)`. Clarify me on this.. will try to provide best possible solution

Comment: Hi Siva, I have worked a way round that problem using the category of test as a filter but I have another problem....I have an Array containng [7, 12, 10, 6, 15] and the code I am using is bring back the maximum as 7 and the minimum as 10.  I am completely confused by this as the other arrays seem to work okay.

Comment: @Dave-69...have you created number array or string array...also when you refer anyone in post refer with @ as it will come in inbox...right now u r msg didn't came to my inbox.. I have come to see any update