# Calculate Maximum of a formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Can we calculate maximum or minimum of a formula field that cannot be summarized using the insert summary option ? Something similar to calculating sum by the three point running total formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values in an array and then take the maximum and minimum of the array to get max and min of formula field.

If you like to see an example, check the answer in below link... which was answered by me for similar question.

[Maximum and Minimum values from a summed Formula in Crystal Reports 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985887/maximum-and-minimum-values-from-a-summed-formula-in-crystal-reports-2008/23028822#23028822)